# 12.04: No sound after installing humble bundle games

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa

I've just installed 12.04.2 on an acer 4830g
Initially the sound worked fine, but then I installed a bunch of games from the humble indie bundle, and now the sound is all dead. I've checked the mixer settings and the output volume is not zero. I've also used the 'Test audio' button in Sound settings - it doesn't say a thing.

I made an alsa-report and I've looked through it. The problem is I don't know what to look for. Any hints on what to look for? My alsa report can be seen here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxb6x083l25adap/alsa-info.txt.i89zeH6YLd

This is its info on my sound card:

```
Codec: Conexant CX20588
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x14f1506c
Subsystem Id: 0x1025054f
Revision Id: 0x100002
```

Currently I have no external speaker attached. The laptop has internal speakers that was proven to work earlier.